# Bootstrap dropdown in column header

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-grid

I've been trying to use the ng-grid 3.0 (ui-grid). I have managed to populate my grid and it's been very responsive and it's features are really amazing. But I'm trying to customize my column headers, as I need more info there.

I can create a custom header cell template, as indicated in the docs, but I don't seem able to use a Bootstrap Dropdown there, it gets cropped and I can't use it at all. Some googling got me thinking it is probably some issue with the overflow attributes, but still I can't solve it. My grid options is as follows:

```
  $scope.columnDefs = [
    { name:'name', displayName: 'Vdd', headerCellTemplate: 'headerTemplate.html' },
    { name:'gender', headerCellTemplate: 'headerTemplate.html' },
    { name:'company' }
  ]

  $scope.gridOptions = {
    columnDefs: $scope.columnDefs,
    rowTemplate: 'rowTemplate.html',
    data: 'data'
  };
```

I have forked an example in plunkr and managed to reproduce my issue:
http://plnkr.co/edit/qdrFiifiz18fxB8w6Aja?p=preview

I want to replace the built-in dropdown menu (since it doesn't seem to allow nesting and sub-menus) and add another one (so in the end, I'd have two dropdown menus in each header cell)

Any help is appreciated =)

Comment: I can get you part way there. Remove the "float:left" and it will appear. But it appears below the view of the main grid. z-index does not help unless you also give it a position:relative. However then it pushes down the header section rather than float above it.  I use a regular <select... tag in the header and it works fine. You can style it to look like a bootstrap dropdown if that is the reason you are using bootstrap. Might be your easiest solution

Answer (score 0):

I am proud to say I think I've figured it out. I've been digging through ui-grid's source code and narrowed it down to this block (lines: 2847 - 2852).

```
function syncHorizontalHeader(scrollEvent){
    var newScrollLeft = scrollEvent.getNewScrollLeft(colContainer, containerCtrl.viewport);
    if (containerCtrl.headerViewport) {
        containerCtrl.headerViewport.scrollLeft = gridUtil.denormalizeScrollLeft(containerCtrl.viewport,newScrollLeft, grid);
    }
}
```

I noticed that `containerCtrl.headerViewport.scrollLeft` was never getting set to `newScrollLeft`. A quick google search led me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068507/why-sometime-scrolltop-scrollleft-not-writable) StackOverflow thread which says that you can't set the `scrollLeft` property of an element if it's `overflow` is set to `visible`.

My solution was to replace `containerCtrl.headerViewport.scrollLeft = gridUtil.denormalizeScrollLeft(containerCtrl.viewport,newScrollLeft, grid);` with `containerCtrl.headerViewport.style.marginLeft = -gridUtil.denormalizeScrollLeft(containerCtrl.viewport,newScrollLeft, grid) + 'px';` which just sets a negative margin on the header. Then add an `overflow:hidden;` style to `.ui-grid-render-container-body` to hide headers that extend beyond the main grid viewport.

Doing this messed up the placement of column menus, but there is an easy fix. On line 514 replace `var containerScrollLeft = renderContainerElm.querySelectorAll('.ui-grid-viewport')[0].scrollLeft;` with `var containerScrollLeft = renderContainerElm.querySelectorAll('.ui-grid-viewport')[0].style.marginLeft;` to use the margin instead of the scroll value in the menu placement calculation.